# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple line 6

Tags: python

```
import os

import time

source = [r'C:\\Documents','/home/swaroop/byte', '/home/swaroop/bin']

target_dir =r'C:\\Documents','/mnt/e/backup/' 

today = target_dir + time.strftime("%Y%m%d")

now = time.strftime('%H%M%S')

os.path.exists(today)

os.mkdir(today)

print 'Successful created directory', today

target = today + os.sep + now + '.zip'

zip_command = "zip -qr '%s' %s" % (target, ' '.join(source))

if os.system(zip_command) == 0:

print 'Successful backup to', target

else:
    print 'Backup FAILED'

today = target_dir + time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

Plees help

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple

Comment: `target_dir =r'C:\\Documents','/mnt/e/backup/'` has a comma separating those strings which makes it a tuple

Comment: Are you trying to create a directory simultaneously in `C:\Documents` and `/mnt/e/backup`?

Comment: I am learning python from book a byte of python i came to page Writing a Python Script Example Backup Script - The First Version,I copy all of code he write python shell  and still i get error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the comma as @MosesKoledoye said, the [book](http://files.swaroopch.com/python/byte_of_python.pdf) has:

```
# 1. The files and directories to be backed up are
# specified in a list.
# Example on Windows:
# source = ['"C:\\My Documents"', 'C:\\Code']     # Example on Mac OS X and Linux:
source = ['/Users/swa/notes']
# Notice we had to use double quotes inside the string # for names with spaces in it.

# 2. The backup must be stored in a
# main backup directory
# Example on Windows:
# target_dir = 'E:\\Backup'
# Example on Mac OS X and Linux:
target_dir = '/Users/swa/backup'
# Remember to change this to which folder you will be using
```

your code has:

```
source = [r'C:\\Documents','/home/swaroop/byte', '/home/swaroop/bin']

target_dir =r'C:\\Documents','/mnt/e/backup/'
```

In the `target_dir` assignment the comma makes the right-side of the assignment a *tuple*.  To join two strings together use a `+`, not a comma:

```
 target_dir =r'C:\\Documents' + '/mnt/e/backup/'
```

better yet, use a single string.  **However**, `/mnt` is a Linux directory name, not a Windows one.  I suspect you actually need:

```
 target_dir = '/mnt/e/backup/'
```

You have also made the Windows path a raw string, which means the two back-slashes will be retained.  Either do this:

```
'C:\\Documents'
```

or this:

```
r'C:\Documents'
```

(unless or course you actually do want `\\`)

Edit:  I just noticed you also have an indentation problem:

```
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
print 'Successful backup to', target
else:
```

should be:

```
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print 'Successful backup to', target
else:
```

Finally, when you say "I copy all the code" and it fails, look to see where yours differs from what it says in the book.